# Zend Translate - get only used strings

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have huge language file on ZF1 project. It`s good idea to make some smart cache, with used strings on page. For example, i have 1000 translated strings and on page http://example.com/test there is only 10 used. So cache should have only 10 strings saved.
It will be huge performance boost, and simple, but there is any easy way to get "used" strings, for example in postDispatch or dispatchLoopShutdown method?

So, summary:

1. is there any easy way to get "used" strings, for example in
   postDispatch or dispatchLoopShutdown method?
2. Maybe somebody have better idea to slice huge translation files with ZF1?

Comment: If you are using gettext as the translation adapter, then the PO file, if managed by POEdit, will have only the strings you used in the code. POEdit has a nice synchronization function.

Comment: Well, a simple hack would be extending your `translate adapter` and override the `translate` method. You can then push used strings to a `Zend_Registry` array key. Should I post a code example for you?

Comment: php-dev i can try to override, thanks for help. Wouter Thielen thanks, i didnt realize that PO files works like You said. So there is some kind of index and file is never fully opened? Sory for my english